# C++ Junior interview question: function to compress a character sequence with only char pointers

Tags: c++, function, compression, definition, c-strings

I was at a job interview the other day and I had the following function to implement:

```
char* Compress (char * text);
```

Rules were also that you are not allowed to use standard libary functions like strlen, strcpy, string etc... So the function has to compress a given character sequence.

For example if the input text is"11112222333344411" after passing it to the Compress function the returned value is: "12341", or if the text input is:"aaAbbBBcCCa" ---> return: aAbBcCa

I am not sure I did everything properly (with memory handling) here so any suggestions would be great. Am I doing it right that I delete the value of temp every time? Also if there is a simpler way to implement this function (without using the standard library functions of course) I would be really pleased to see it.

```
#include <iostream>

char* Compress(char* text) {

    char* temp;
    char* _compText;

    int size = 1;

    _compText = nullptr;

    for (size_t i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        if (text[i] != text[i + 1]) {

            ++size;

            temp = _compText;

            _compText = new char[size];

            for (size_t j = 0; j < size-2; ++j)
            {
                _compText[j] = temp[j];
            }

            _compText[size-2] = text[i];
            _compText[size-1] = '\0';
            delete[] temp;
        }

    }

    return _compText;
}

int main()
{
    char t[] = "111122222233333444444555555111";

    char* compedT;

    std::cout << "Before:\n";

    std::cout << t;

    compedT = Compress(t);

    std::cout << "\nAfter: \n";

    std::cout << compedT;

    delete[] compedT;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is going to be opinion-based, but in mine, you could make this a lot cleaner by doing two passes, one to calculate the length of the output and one to generate it.

Comment: I wouldn't consider dynamically allocating and deallocating an array every iteration to be a good answer

Comment: If you want help improving working code you should post this on [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  If you do decide to do so please delete the question here.

Comment: Also, do you know if the function is actually supposed to allocate new memory?

Comment: If the string passed in has zero-length, i.e. the first element is `'\0'`, then you'll return a `nullptr` instead of a zero-length string. Also, the variable `size` doesn't seem representative of what you'd expect it to do.

Comment: I will delete it later I got enough help already. Thank you for the answers.
The size supposed to represent how many char-s are actually in the _compText
and the only rule was that you are not allowed to use the std libary functions and data structures, but as @Vlad from Moscow already poitner out with his answer I dont even have to use "new".

Comment: @Near It is not a good idea to delete the question because there is already a reference to it. The question can help other beginners.

Comment: If you believe that the code works correctly, consider presenting your work (with its unit tests) in a more-complete fashion over at [codereview.se].  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.  Before you do that, make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".

Comment: "SOLVED" without an accepted answer with an explaination will be a bit disappointing for others with similar queries coming here looking for answers.

Comment: Done. Are we good now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function initially is implemented incorrectly.

The type of the function is

```
char* Compress (char * text);
                ^^^^^^^
```

that is its parameter is not `const char *`, This means that the function should update the source string in place and return pointer to its first character. There is no need to allocate dynamically memory to perform the task.

The function can be defined as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

char * Compress( char *s )
{
    for ( char *p = s, *q = s; *q; )
    {
        if ( *++q != *p ) *++p = *q;
    }

    return s;
}

int main()
{
    char s[] = "11112222333344411";

    std::cout << Compress( s ) << '\n';
}
```

Its output is

```
12341
```

Or the function can look also the following way

```
char * Compress( char *s )
{
    for ( char *p = s, *q = s; *q; )
    {
        if ( ( *++q != *p ) and ( ++p != q ) ) *p = *q;
    }

    return s;
}
```

As for your function implementation then you should read warnings as for example

```
warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'size_t' {aka 'long unsigned int'} and 'int' [-Wsign-compare]
   34 |             for (size_t j = 0; j < size-2; ++j)
      |                                ~~^~~~~~~~
```

And your function returns `nullptr` for an empty string. This looks logically inconsistent. And the function is very inefficient.:)

And do not use names that start with underscore.

Comment: This is a really helpful answer thank you. I suppose you would have mentioned if there is something wrong with memory handling tho, now I see I made this simple task so difficult. Thank you.

Comment: I meant like this is a simple task and I made a difficult solution for that. Yes thank you. ^^

Comment: Actually one more question what IDE do you use or only text editor? For me it's Visual Studio 2019 on windows obviously and it didnt show any warnings. I am thinking about switching to Linux and keep practicing I heard it is a better practice.

Answer (score 1):

> Does my code have memory leak?

As far as I can see, no; there is no memory leak.

That said, the use of bare owning pointers makes it difficult to spot memory leaks. They are a bad design choice, especially when transferring ownership to outside of the function. At the very least, there should be a comment near the function declaration that should document how the caller must clean up the allocation. If you need a dynamic array, a better solution is to use a container.

> Am I doing it right that I delete the value of temp everytime?

As far memory leaks are concerned yes, you do need to delete every allocation. But reallocating memory on every iteration is unnecessary, and quite slow. In fact, there doesn't appear to be need for any dynamic allocation (See Vlad's answer).

Comment: The first time through, `size - 2` will be 0, so the contents for loop will not run. I don't think it's a good design, but I don't think it'll dereference a null pointer.

Comment: No, on first iteration `size = 2` which is not smaller than 2, so it never gets to that loop the first time when `temp = nullptr`

Comment: @ThomasJager ah. You're correct. It's too complicated algorithm for my brain.

Comment: Thank you also a helpful answer, yes I am aware that "naked" pointers are dangerous. I just really wanted to solve it wihtout using anything but pointers and primitive data types, I think if I can solve it with very basic stuff I will understand the more difficult things later. One more question how to warn the caller about the clean up?

Comment: @Near Write a comment that describes what the caller must do.